# Is it possible to "inherit" tests with xUnit.net?

Tags: c#, xunit.net

I have a concrete class called EventManager and a subclass called ScheduledEventManager. I would like ScheduledEventManager to have to pass the same tests as EventManager plus a few additional ones. Is this possible with xUnit.net?

EDIT: I just realized that my case is a little more complicated than this. I'm using nested classes to keep my tests more organized. Example:

```
public class EventManagerTests
{
    public class WhenAnEventIsFired
    {
        [Fact]
        void ItNotifiesSubscribers()
        {
            // Perform the test
        }
    }
}

public class ScheduledEventManagerTests
{
    // How to I inherit the above tests since they are in nested classes?
}
```

It seems to me that this is not possible, but maybe one of you geniuses knows something I don't.

Comment: Create a parameterized test that takes an instance of your base class as the SUT, invoke the test with an instance of the sub class.

Comment: This sounds great, but can you give an example for the benefit of me and anyone else who finds this post in the future?

Comment: @KevinCraft, here's an example of a benefit in inheritance in tests (if that's what you're asking): https://masterofprogramming.blogspot.com/2016/08/well-organized-unit-tests.html
Another use is testing multiple implementations of the same interface:  You can write all your tests in an abstract class, and create a subclass for each implementation that you wish to test.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a base test class in Xunit to test interface implementations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60218599/how-do-i-create-a-base-test-class-in-xunit-to-test-interface-implementations)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Create a parameterized test that takes an instance of your base class as the SUT, and invoke the test with an instance of the sub class. Here's a (contrived) example using NUnit, which results in one passing and one failing test:

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual int DoSomething()
    {
        return 10;
    }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public override int DoSomething()
    {
        return 9;
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    private Foo[] _foos = { new Foo(), new Bar() };

    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource("_foos")]
    public void When_DoSomething_Is_Invoked_Then_A_Power_Of_Ten_Is_Returned(Foo sut)
    {
        Assert.That(sut.DoSomething() % 10, Is.EqualTo(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your code is using NUnit, not XUnit. Regardless, I ended up having to abandon my nested class approach and use the methods with underscores approach like you. I also used simple inheritance to share the tests between classes (in my case ScheduledEventManagerTests inherited from EventManagerTests). The key was for the tests in EventManagerTests to be at least protected (public would also work).

Comment: I mentioned that it was NUnit in the answer, I think the equivalent to `TestCaseSource` in xUnit is `PropertyData`, and you would need to mark the test as `Theory` rather than `Fact`.

Answer (score 12):

Yes You can:

```
public abstract class EventManagerTests
{
     protected IEventManager _ev;
     protected EventManagerTests(IEventManager ev)
     {
          _ev = ev;
     }

     [Fact]
     public void SharedTest()
     {
        // Perform _ev test
     }

}

public class ScheduledEventManagerTests : EventManagerTests
{
    public ScheduledEventManagerTests():base(new ScheduledEventManager())
    {
    }

    // It will inherit tests from the base abstract class
}


public class UnScheduledEventManagerTests : EventManagerTests
{
    public UnScheduledEventManagerTests():base(new UnScheduledEventManager())
    {
    }

    // It will inherit tests from the base abstract class
}
```

[image]

Comment: notice the abstract base class, it prevents the runner from instantiating the base class for test runs. you probably want that

Comment: yes that is why it has to be abstract because you don't want the runner to run the base. It is just shared code.