# How do I create a base test class in Xunit to test interface implementations?

Tags: c#, xunit

I am writing a test suite for a class library using C# and XUnit. In the library are a number of classes that implement an interface. I could simply copy-paste the same tests for the interface implementation into each test class but I was wondering if there is a neater solution using some test base class which can be inherited from and run automatically without calling each method in turn in each test class.

This [article on codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/609259/unit-testing-interfaces-in-net) demonstrates how it would be done in mstest using an abstract base class marked with **TestClass**. A summary is given below. However I cannot figure out if there is an equivalent using xunit. Does anyone know how to approach this? The xunit docs say there is no equivalent to **TestClass** in mstest.

Interface

```
public interface IDoSomething
{
  int SearchString(string stringToSearch, string pattern);
}
```

One of many classes implementing interface

```
public class ThisDoesSomething : IDoSomething
{
  public int SearchString(string stringToSearch, string pattern);
  {
    // implementation
  }
}
```

Interface Test base class

```
[TestClass]
public abstract class IDoSomethingTestBase
{
  public abstract IDoSomething GetDoSomethingInstance();

  [TestMethod]
  public void BasicTest()
  {
    IDoSomething ids = GetDoSomethingInstance();
    Assert.AreEqual("a_string", ids.SearchString("a_string", ".*");
  }
}
```

Test class that tests the class implementing interface

```
[TestClass]
public class ThisDoesSomething_Tests : IDoSomethingTestBase
{
  public override IDoSomething GetDoSomethingInstance()
  {
    return new ThisDoesSomething();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works exactly the same way...

```cs
public abstract class IDoSomethingTestBase
{
  protected readonly IDoSomething InstanceUnderTest;

  protected IDoSomethingTestBase(IDoSomething instanceUnderTest){
    InstanceUnderTest = instanceUnderTest;
  }

  [Fact]
  public void BasicTest()
  {
    Assert.AreEqual("a_string", InstanceUnderTest.SearchString("a_string", ".*");
  }
}
```

Actual test class:

```cs
public class ThisDoesSomething_Tests : IDoSomethingTestBase
{
  public ThisDoesSomething_Tests(): base(new ThisDoesSomething()) { }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do you then debug the test against an instance class? The test method is in the base class.

Comment: In Visual Studio they will show up as separate test classes (the base class itself won't show) in the test explorer (right click a test and choose debug).
In VS Code there is a handy plugin which does the same thing: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.dotnet-test-explorer